# Windows 8.1 suddenly booting slowly, ntfs event id 98 appearing in the system log for each drive

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, ntfs

This morning my PC took much longer to boot than normal, 60 seconds instead of the usual 10 or so. Investigating the event viewer I see that now on every boot there's an ntfs event 98, example below, for each drive, each reporting that the drive is healthy, but the checking is obviously slowing the system boot.

Is this a sign of impending drive failure? There's no sign of any software or driver change since yesterday.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs
Date:          03/10/2014 23:49:31
Event ID:      98
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (2)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      The_Count
Description:
Volume C: (\Device\HarddiskVolume4) is healthy.  No action is needed.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs" Guid="{3FF37A1C-A68D-4D6E-8C9B-F79E8B16C482}" />
    <EventID>98</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000002</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-10-03T22:49:31.433244300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>666</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="192" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>The_Count</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="DriveName">C:</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceName">\Device\HarddiskVolume4</Data>
    <Data Name="CorruptionActionState">0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Try safe mode; is that any better?

Comment: Event98 = warning about corrupted Volume **(<event channel="SYSTEM" keywords="VolumeCorruptionActionStateChange" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.event_VOLUME_CORRUPTION_ACTION_STATE)" symbol="NTFS_VOLUME_CORRUPTION_ACTION_STATE" template="tid_VOLUME_CORRUPTION_ACTION_STATE" value="98" />**. But your drive is fine.

Comment: thanks for the responses, the log entries still appear in safe mode. I've run chkdsk on all volumes and no errors are reported. I've used chkntfs /x c: to try and stop the system checking c: on boot, but the ntfs event entries still appear for it. Disconnecting the mechanical drive reduces the boot time considerably (but of course this is not an option) but why does the boot process need to even access it, no part of the OS is on it?